# SourceTree 3.0.1 stuck with Cannot Spawn, cant pull, push or fetch

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I recently upgraded SourceTree 3.0.6 and since then I am not able to pull, fetch and push. I have checked for all the credentials and git repo. Restarted machine.

I have been getting stuck on this below window and Error - Cannot spawn
[image]

Everything looks to be ok with gitbash though.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, but only with one repository

Comment: @MariusB, Any luck? I tried an older version but having the same issue on older version too now.

Comment: I am now using 3.0.8 and I need to switch between `Embedded` and `System` Git version inside SourceTree settings depending on the repository. Some of the repositories work only with `Embedded` and some of them only with `System` Git version... More annoying is that when using `Embedded` version lots of login popups constantly appear

Comment: @MariusB, Thanks it worked... What I did is, I switched between Embedded & system also tried to pull using terminal.. & now it's working...

Comment: Since it works not only for me, but also for you, I posted my comment as an answer. Feel free to upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the source of this this bug, but switching between `Embedded` and `System` Git version inside SourceTree settings seems to help. Some of the repositories work only with `Embedded` and some of them only with `System` Git version.